# Changing the limits of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

The integral $\int_0^{\infty}$ can always be written in the form $\int_0^1$.

It is written in the *Inside Interesting Integrals* by Paul J. Nahin, p. 3.

Can the integral $\int_a^{\infty}$ where $a$ is finite number be written in the form $\int_0^1$ ?

Comment: If you want the form $\int_0^{\infty}$ put $t=x-a$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Does it mean that I can do the same trick in $\int_a^{\infty}$ where a is finite without getting the form $\int_0^{\infty}$ as you said?

Comment: Have you tried $t=\frac{b-a}{b-x}x$ to get $\int_a^\infty f(t)dt$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. In this book which I mentioned is written that the integral $\int_0^{\infty}$ can always be written in the form $\int_0^1$. Can I do the same thing with the form $\int_a^{\infty}$ if a is not equal $0$.

Comment: We went from $0,\infty$ to $a,\infty$ and now it is $0,1$. More focus please. Before you randomly pick further integration limits: did my last comment help at all?

Comment: @KurtG. I have tried you substitution but have not got any result. I changed my answer. I was unclear on my unswer. I will not randomly pick further integration limits. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0\le a\le b<\infty$. We want to transform the integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ to $\int_c^\infty g(t)\,dt$ with $c>0$. To solve this take
$$
t=c\,\frac{b-a}{b-x}\,,\text{ or equivalently }\quad x=b-c\,\frac{b-a}{t}\,.
$$
From
$$
\frac{dt}{dx}=c\,\frac{b-a}{(b-x)^2}
$$
we see that
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx&=\int_{t(a)}^{t(b)}f(x)\,\frac{(b-x)^2}{c(b-a)}\,dt=\frac{1}{c(b-a)}\int_c^\infty f\left(b-c\,\frac{b-a}{t}\right)\frac{c^2(b-a)^2}{t^2}\,dt\\[3mm]
&=\int_c^\infty f\left(b-c\,\frac{b-a}{t}\right)\frac{c(b-a)}{t^2}\,dt\,.
\end{align}
Can you now answer your last question? Hint: make your $a$ equal to my $c$ and
set my $[a,b]$ to $[0,1]$.